# Elements on page cause width to be stretched allowing for scrolling when dragging across text

Tags: html, css

I am currently helping develop a page but one of the skewed diagonal lines we have placed on the page are currently going outside the width of the page allowing the site to be scrolled to a spot where the element ends. THis isn't such a big problem when hiding the overflow-x on desktop but on mobile it is very easy to scroll to the side and go to a blank white space.

As you can see I've tried hiding the overflow, I've also tried setting the body and html to 100% width but no luck on that either. The only thing that stops it is setting overflow:hidden; on the body tag, but this stops scrolling down as well.

[image]

The CSS:

```
body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
/*Diagonal Lines*/
#diagonalLine1, #diagonalLine2 {
    position: absolute;
}
#diagonalLine1{
    top: 100%;
    margin-left: 58px;
    max-width: 91%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #FFC616;
    transform:skew(30deg,30deg) scale(1.5, 1.5);
    -webkit-transform:skew(26deg,26deg) scale(1.5, 1.5);
    -ms-transform:skew(26deg,26deg) scale(1.5, 1.5);
    -moz-transform:skew(30deg,30deg) scale(2, 2);
    overflow: hidden;
}
#diagonalLine2{
    top: 282%;
    margin-left:33px;
    max-width:90%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #FFC616;
    transform:skew(30deg,30deg) scale(1.5, 1.5);
    -webkit-transform:skew(160deg,160deg) scale(1.5, 1.5);
    -ms-transform:skew(160deg,160deg) scale(1.5, 1.5);
    -moz-transform:skew(30deg,30deg) scale(2, 2);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This isn't entirely how it is displaying, but I'm trying to disable the horizontal scrolling and just have the shapes escape out of the element rather than stretching the body.

https://jsfiddle.net/co2re0g2/

The marked answer is correct but never worked in our environment. I used the following Javascript instead to correct the issue.

```
$(function() {

   var $body = $(document);
   $body.bind('scroll', function() {
       // "Disable" the horizontal scroll.
       if ($body.scrollLeft() !== 0) {
           $body.scrollLeft(0);
       }
   });

});
```

Comment: Try `overflow-x: hidden; overlfow-y: auto` on body.

Comment: Yep, tried that. No luck.

Comment: 'splash' is a HTML tag? And body a class? This target seems to be wrong. I suggest yout trying to reproduce the problem only with the minimal elements that are producing it (html, body, div, ...). Maybe you solve it by simplyfing and if you don't, you will be able to provide us the complete code that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such HTML tag called `splash` neither do you define an object with class `.splash` in your fiddle.

by changing the first CSS rule to

```
body {
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

your problem should be fixed as I show in this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Loxos/co2re0g2/1/).

### Update

to prevent the undesired scrolling effect you need to put the whole page in a wrapper like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="background">
        <div id="diagonalLine1" class="fullWidth"></div>
        <div id="diagonalLine2" class="fullWidth"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>
            Here goes your content.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and further add some additional styling to hide the x-overflow parts:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
.wrapper{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.background{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.content{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
}
```

You may also have a look at this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Loxos/co2re0g2/4/).

Comment: You are correct, unfortunately if you drag and scroll on the element it will still move outside the boundaries of the body. This is the behaviour I am trying to avoid. Setting overflow to hidden does stop this, but removes the y scrolling, which can't be activated back without again introducing non-intended behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, this works in a dev enviroment but when attempted to actually be put on our CMS it doesn't work again. Not sure why but I've found a Javascript solution that works. I will still mark this question as correct as it technically is!